# Looking for STM32F4 Vdd 5V

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, pcb-design, stm32, stm32f4

I have to replace Renasas M30853 MCU with STM32F407 MCU in a circuit. The earlier MCU uses power supply Vdd = +5V as well as all the analog and digital circuit that is connected with it. How can I use STM32F407 MCU or any of its variant to use +5V power supply?

Comment: No STM32F4 microcontrollers will work on 5V input, as far as I'm aware. You'll have to add a voltage regulator.

Comment: No variant uses a 5V supply for that processor... You will have to modify the supply to provide 3.3v, which may be as simple as selecting a new regulator, but it depends on the other stuff on the board and the supply circuit.

Comment: You can't use any STM32 on 5V power, look into STR7 or NXP's catalog (former freescale) for suitable part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no STM32 parts that run on 5V, but they would work in 5V circuits. With some precautions.

**Power supply**

The maximum supply voltage is 3.6V, there is no way around that.

**Digital I/O**

All I/O pins except `PA4` and `PA5` (DAC outputs) are 5V tolerant **in digital input or open-drain output mode**.

You can connect incoming 5V digital signals directly to the I/O pins.

Digital output high level voltage is at least V<sub>DD</sub>-1.3V, that is > 2.0V at V<sub>DD</sub>=3.3V, good enough for TTL inputs.

Use an external pull-up resistor to 5V if you need output voltage above 2V, or on bidirectional signals like I<sup>2</sup>C.

Important rule: if voltages above V<sub>DD</sub> can appear on an I/O pin, then the only safe modes for that pin are digital input or open-drain output, and the internal pullup resistor should not be used.

**Analog I/O**

You are unfortunately on your own here, output levels must be externally amplified if necessary, input levels must be divided or clamped.